# Updating highlighted rows in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have a `JTable` with a list of information. I highlighted some of the rows using:

```
myTable.addRowSelectionInterval(number,number);
myTable.setSelectionBackground(Color.yellow);
```

`number` is just the number of the row to be highlighted.

My program reads from a file which contains a list of numbers and then highlights the according rows. This is so when I close the program and open it back up, the highlighted rows will remain highlighted.

The problem is that I can't seem to update my `JTable` if I use

```
addRowSelectionInterval(number,number);
```

Is there any way to "refresh" a `JTable`?

I've seen some code used to refresh the values on a table but that doesn't help.

I don't know if it's because I'm just highlighting the rows.

I'm using the default `JTable`.

I don't know anything about "models". This is my first time making a GUI.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this? I would gladly appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're in Swing's thread when updating the selection interval? If not, you can call your selection using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Answer (score 1):

The [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below produces the expected result. As @P. Lalonde comments, verify that you are updating the selection on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Updating the `TableModel` will update the view automatically, but the current selection is a view property.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16765450/230513 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTable table = new JTable(
            new String[][]{{"One"},{"Two"}, {"Three"}},
            new String[]{"Ordinal"});
        table.addRowSelectionInterval(1, 1);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: My program already does that same thing.

I think maybe I didn't explain my problem in detail. 

What I basically have is a list of jobs in the Jtable.

Example:

job1
job2
job3
job4

Lets say that jobs 1 and 2 are already highlighted. I want to hightlight job4, but I want jobs 1 and 2 to remain highlighted.

Comment: Using `table.addRowSelectionInterval(2, 2)` works for me in an `ActionListener`. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you encountered; start from the example above.